# Android How to show route between markers on googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I'm creating an App that will show the location of the user and put a marker to that position. After the user moves. The marker would be removed and a new marker would be created. Now. I want to make markers on Point A and Point B to be hardcoded into the app and show the route on the map. It shall use the nearest road on the map. I've done some research but only find old code which dated 5 years back. Could anyone be kind enough to guide me through this.

The Point A and Point B is on LocationChanged method.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    LatLng coordinate;
    Marker startPerc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabledGPS = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean enabledWiFi = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
        // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to 
        // go to the settings
        if (!enabledGPS) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {

        //do something
    }


}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 300, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lat =  location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + lat+","+lng,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + coordinate.latitude+","+coordinate.longitude,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(map!=null){
        map.clear();
    }
    //map.clear();
    GoogleMap map;
    if(startPerc!=null){
        startPerc.remove();
    }
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    startPerc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(coordinate)
      .title("Start")
      .snippet("Your Position")
      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 20));



    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                    .position(new LatLng(3.214732, 101.747047))
                    .title("Point A")
                    .snippet("Bus Stop")
                    .flat(true));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                    .position(new LatLng(3.214507, 101.749697))
                    .title("Point B")
                    .snippet("Bus Stop")
                    .flat(true));



startPerc.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

}


@ Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
void Delay(int Seconds){
    long Time = 0;
    Time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < Time+(Seconds*1000));
}
}
```

New code provided by K Neeraj. It still crash sadly please check.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    LatLng coordinate;
    Marker startPerc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabledGPS = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean enabledWiFi = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
        // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to 
        // go to the settings
        if (!enabledGPS) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);



        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Provider " + provider,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {

        //do something
    }


}


/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 300, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lat =  location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + lat+","+lng,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + coordinate.latitude+","+coordinate.longitude,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    if(map!=null){
        map.clear();
    }

    GoogleMap map;
    if(startPerc!=null){
        startPerc.remove();
    }
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    startPerc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(coordinate)
      .title("Start")
      .snippet("Your Position")
      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 12));




    startPerc.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

 // Assign your origin and destination
 // These points are your markers coordinates
 LatLng origin = new LatLng(3.214732, 101.747047);
 LatLng dest = new LatLng(3.214507, 101.749697);

 // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
 String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

 DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

 // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
 downloadTask.execute(url);
 }


 private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){


     // Origin of route
     String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

     // Destination of route
     String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

     // Sensor enabled
     String sensor = "sensor=false";

     // Building the parameters to the web service
     String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

     // Output format
     String output = "json";

     // Building the url to the web service
     String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

     return url;
 }



 /** A method to download json data from url */
     private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
         String data = "";
         InputStream iStream = null;
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
         try{
             URL url = new URL(strUrl);

         // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
         urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

         // Connecting to url
         urlConnection.connect();

         // Reading data from url
         iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

         String line = "";
         while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
             sb.append(line);
         }

         data = sb.toString();

         br.close();

     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
     }finally{
         iStream.close();
         urlConnection.disconnect();
     }
     return data;
 }

 // Fetches data from url passed
 private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

     // Downloading data in non-ui thread
     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

         // For storing data from web service
         String data = "";

         try{
             // Fetching the data from web service
             data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
         }
         return data;
     }

     // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
     // doInBackground()
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

         // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
         parserTask.execute(result);
     }
 }

 /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
 private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

     // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
     @Override
     protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

         JSONObject jObject;
         List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

         try{
             jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
             DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

             // Starts parsing data
             routes = parser.parse(jObject);
         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return routes;
     }

     // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
         ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
         PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
         MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

         // Traversing through all the routes
         for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
             points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
             lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

             // Fetching i-th route
             List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

             // Fetching all the points in i-th route
             for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                 HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                 double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                 double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                 LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                 points.add(position);
             }

             // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
             lineOptions.addAll(points);
             lineOptions.width(2);
             lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
         }

         // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
         map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
     }
 }




@ Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
void Delay(int Seconds){
    long Time = 0;
    Time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < Time+(Seconds*1000));
}
}
```

Then I created a new DirectionJSONParser.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
            routes.add(path);
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (Exception e){
}

return routes;
}
/**
* Method to decode polyline points
* Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
* */
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
            (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
}
```

Comment: See a [Tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/)

Comment: I'm getting this error when importing the file. What should i do?
[2015-02-03  - Path Google Maps API v2] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:18'

Comment: Right click on the Project > Properties > Android > Select a version > Apply

Comment: Yes that solved the error. But this one is for Joan for giving me the link to the tutorial. I was trying to understand the tutorial. The code that you gave me still crashes. Please help =(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
....
 startPerc.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

// Assign your origin and destination
// These points are your markers coordinates
LatLng origin = new LatLng(3.214732, 101.747047);
LatLng dest = new LatLng(3.214507, 101.749697);

// Getting URL to the Google Directions API
String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

// Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
downloadTask.execute(url);
}


private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){


    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}



/** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}
```

Have a look at this tutorial,

[Drawing Driving Route Directions Between Two Locations Using Google Directions In Google Map Android Api v2](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

It shows how to draw Route map between two points.

Comment: I'm very new to this. can you guide me on what can i put into my code? The code does run well. I can put 2 marker by manually but I don't know how to implement into my project

Comment: It crashed. Shows up the map a few second and crash. 2 quick question. 1) I need to create DirectionsJSONParser.class and put the code of class DirectionsJSONParser from the link right? 

2) When I copy pasted into the eclipse. Only at the line

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
gives a warning.
The warning is "The value of the local variable markerOptions is not used"

Comment: Sadly no. It crash when loading up the map. It shows my location for a while then crash. The error is java.lang.nullpointerexception if I'm reading it correctly

Comment: Can you also include you logcat output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583323/android-how-to-link-markers-between-each-other-using-roads-in-googlemaps

Comment: Can you pm me K Neeraj? I need someone to help me with this. I can pay you if you can solve my problem

Comment: It works well and the routes are drawn, but it takes a lot of time, sometimes I get ANR even with a few coordinates, do you know why and what could be done?

Comment: Great answer, how can I Increase the width of the route?

Comment: @grant Change this line `lineOptions.width(2);`.

Comment: I copy/pasted this code, but it crashed with the latest version of google.maps.services that is 0.9.0  , with this exception : NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalDateTime  . I switched to googl.maps.services:0.2.11 and it is ok now

Comment: In 2022 it requires an API key (and API access is paid)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full code with minor tweaks. It's just a prettier.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.eddress.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class GoogleMapsPath {

    public GoogleMap map;

    public GoogleMapsPath(Activity context, GoogleMap map, LatLng origin, LatLng dest){
        this.map = map;

        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin,dest);
        FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();
        FetchUrl.execute(url);

    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }


    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }


    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }


    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                Log.d("ParserTask",jsonData[0].toString());
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
                Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                Log.d("ParserTask","Executing routes");
                Log.d("ParserTask",routes.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ParserTask",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(8);
                lineOptions.color(R.color.globalRedLight);

                Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            if(lineOptions != null) {
                map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/