# include all the route points of route in map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I want to show polyline  between start point and end point of particular route in mapview with lite mode in recycler view.for that I used latlngbounds to include all the route point but when route is so long say for 20 km one of two point is not showing in mapview ..any idea how to achieve this..any help is appreciated

Comment: I think your problem is in your code, on how to setup the polylines. I suggest you to read more on the documents about [polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#polylines). Also check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295199/android-how-to-show-route-between-markers-on-googlemaps) and this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/) to serve you as a guide.

Comment: OK I will check once again @KENdi..and will inform further more I have list of points based on that I draw polyline no API call is required ..

Comment: thanks @KEndi for your help , i solved it by including all route points on polyline and then move camera to that bounds,and then zoom out the camera..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by including all route points on polyline and then move camera to that bounds,and then zoom out the camera..

Answer (score 4):

I had managed this scenario by setting the padding on four sides by following code snippet.

```
mGoogleMap.setPadding(100, 100, 100, 100); //GoogleMap mGoogleMap
```

Then add two latlng to `LatLngBounds.Builder`. 
Add builder to bounds, then to Map.

```
public void setViewPortToBounds(LatLng point1, LatLng point2) {
    mGoogleMap.setPadding(100, 100, 100, 100);
    mapBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    mapBuilder.include(point1);
    mapBuilder.include(point2);
    mapBounds = mapBuilder.build();

    mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(onCameraChangeListener);

}

GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener onCameraChangeListener = new GoogleMap
        .OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mapBounds, 0));
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
    }
};
```